# Regex: Give priority to optional pattern

Tags: c#, regex

Let's say I have a string like this:

```
555 3553 666 555
```

And a regex like this

```
var pat = new Regex("3?553?");
```

When the string above is matched `pat.Match(mystring)` the result returned will be "55".
I need the result returned to be "3553" if possible, and if not, then only then I want the result to be "55". As in: The `3?` is optional and doesn't have to be there, but if it is it will always be matched first.

So this `555 3553 666 555` will return 3553

And this `222 5555 777` will return 55

Is this possible to achieve without using two separate regex definitions?

Thank you.

Comment: This is not a duplicate - at least not of the linked question since word boundary anchors won't allow the desired match of  `55` in the second case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to use a priority over matches, if yes! I think below code can help you:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(txt, @"(?<G1>3553)|(?<G2>55)").OfType<Match>();
var res = matches
        .GroupBy(x => x.Success)
        .Select(x => 
            new {
                    Success = x.Key,
                    G = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Max(w => w.Groups["G1"].Value))
                        ? x.Max(w => w.Groups["G1"].Value)
                        : x.Max(w => w.Groups["G2"].Value)
                })
        .SingleOrDefault();
```

[**C# Demo**](http://rextester.com/IQPPB63108)

Answer (score 1):

Regex engines always go through the string from left to right (assuming a left-to-right script). In your case, the first two characters match the regex, therefore it returns.

So, instead of stopping after the first match, you need to do all the matches and choose the longest one. However, there is a caveat: Regex matches can't overlap (every character can be matched only once). Therefore, in a string like

```
55553553
```

your regex would return `55`, `553`, and `553`.

The solution is to use a [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), combined with a capturing group:

```
var pat = new Regex("(?=(3?553?))", "g");
```

and get all its matches

```
var match = pat.exec(subject);
while (match != null) {
    // matched text: match[1], add that to an array
    }
    match = pat.exec(subject);
}
```

Then choose the longest match.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex matches `55` simply because that was the first match it can find. There is nothing to do with priorities.

I think what you want here is to get the longest match. You should use `Matches` to get all the matches and get the longest one by checking `Length`.

```
var matches = Regex.Matches("555 3553 666 555", "3?553?");
var longestMatch = matches.Cast<Match>().OrderByDescending(x => x.Value.Length).First().Value
```

Comment: Problem: Matches can't overlap - try it on `5553533`.